# How to get a list of exponentially distributed points sampled in a range

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, distributions, sampling

I want to get 256 points exponentially sampled in a range, and then get its histogram.

If I plot PDF, I get the following:

```
Plot[Table[PDF[ExponentialDistribution[\[Lambda]], x], {\[Lambda], {10}}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 0.5}, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All]
```

But when I try to get a list, I am not sure how to proceed:

```
list = N[Table[PDF[ExponentialDistribution[1/10], x], {x, 0, 0.5}]] //Sort
Histogram[list]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
trdist = TruncatedDistribution[{0, 0.04}, ExponentialDistribution[10]];
sample = RandomVariate[trdist, 256];

Histogram[sample, {Subdivide[-0.04, 0.08, 15]}]
```

[image: hist]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RandomVariate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html) to generate samples for given distributions.

```
sample = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1/10], 10000] ;
Show[Histogram[sample,100,"ProbabilityDensity"],Plot[PDF[ExponentialDistribution[1/10],x],{x,0,50}]]
```

Comment: I also want to specify the range like 256 exponentially distributed points with decay constant as 10 (or any other number) but ranging between 0 and 30 only.

Comment: @tabi_k Maybe with [TruncatedDistribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TruncatedDistribution.html?q=TruncatedDistribution) ?

Comment: `TruncatedDistribution[{0, 0.04}, 
 RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[10], 256]]`
Didn't work @b.gates.you.know.what

Comment: @tabi_k Please see answer.